# How to search an array that is an object

Tags: php, arrays, class, foreach

I am a little confused about the array_search function (or maybe I am trying to use the incorrect thing.) I have a bunch of transaction objects, (transactions about a customer) each is an array of values. After passing in an email address, I get an object that is one transaction where that email address was used. Example is below. I get it from the command `print_r($results)`:

```
    stdClass Object
(
    [OverallStatus] => OK
    [RequestID] => 4564564654-65465464565-4654654
    [Results] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [thing1] => 
                    [thing2] => 
                    [Status] => Active
                    [ID] => 5555555555
                    [email_addy] => someaddy@something.com
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [thing1] => 
                    [thing2] => 
                    [Status] => Active
                    [ID] => 6666666666
                    [email_addy] => someaddy@something.com
                )

            [2] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [thing1] => 
                    [thing2] => 
                    [Status] => Active
                    [ID] => 6666666666
                    [email_addy] => someaddy@something.com
                )

        )

)
```

I get this output with no trouble at all. My issue is that I need to identify when someone has a specific ID. I was trying to use a foreach but I am not getting back what I need. The code and output is below.

```
foreach ($results as $key => $value) {      
echo "Key: $key; Value: $value<br />\n"; 
}
```

Output is

```
Key: OverallStatus; Value: OK

Key: RequestID; Value: 4564564654-65465464565-4654654

Key: Results; Value: Array
```

All I really need to know is if the customer has an ID of `5555555555`. This number will always stay the same. Am I going in the wrong direction here?

Comment: You have to access the Results Property of your $results object ... do `foreach ($results->Results)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have array of `object` , so you should get first the array `results` , and then iterate over it,try this :

```
foreach ($results->Results  as $key => $value) {      
 if($value->ID == 55555555) echo 'found at position'.$key;//if id is unique , add a break;
}
```

Comment: This method is similar to Sumoanand's and I seem to not be able to get the if to work. I added an else that pumped out a fail message and I got that three times, one for each time through the class.

Never mind. I am a moron. Your code worked wonderfully Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You need to iterate through $results->Results.

```
foreach ($results->Results as $key => $value) {    

if($value->ID == 5555555555)
  print "Match found";

}
```

Comment: I think this should do it. I added an else

    }else{
    echo 'grr';
So I got something back either way. I got "grr grr grr" so it is going through all three but it is not seeing the ID. I added quotes around the ID as well to check that that was not the issue but I received the same output.

Answer (score 1):

You should loop again for `results` array. Try following `foreach`

```
foreach ($results as $key => $value) {
    if($key == "Results") {
        foreach($value as $v) {
            if($v->ID == "5555555555") {
                echo "I found you";
                break;
            }
        }
    } else {
        echo "Key: $key; Value: $value<br />\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop through '$results->Results' and check in loop if the ID=5555555555 like this:

```
foreach ($results->Results as $value) {      
    if($value->ID == 5555555555) {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be something like the following:

```
$transactions = $results->Results;  //get results array

foreach ($transactions as $transaction) { // loop through each transaction object.
    echo $transaction->ID . '<br />';  // print out the id of each transaction.
}
```